# Android file.canRead() = false when choosing image but not when TAKING photo

Tags: android, image

I have 2 buttons on an "upload image" page for users to upload an image to a web service.  One is for selecting an image that is on your device, the other for taking a photo with your camera.

```
thisFragment.findViewById(R.id.btnChooseImage).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Assert.assertNotNull("file uri not null before firing intent", mFileUri);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            //this is the file that the camera app will write to
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mFileUri);
            startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    });

    thisFragment.findViewById(R.id.btnTakePhoto).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Assert.assertNotNull("file uri not null before firing intent", mFileUri);
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            //this is the file that the camera app will write to
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mFileUri);
            startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    });
```

btnTakePhoto works fine when it loads an ImageView with the result when I TAKE a photo, but when I CHOOSE a photo using the other button the imageView is blank...

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if(data != null) {
            if(data.getData() != null) {
                Log.v(LOG_TAG, "intent data: " + data.getData().toString());
            }
            if(data.getAction() != null) {
                Log.v(LOG_TAG, "intent action: " + data.getAction().toString());
            }
            if(data.getExtras() != null) {
                Log.v(LOG_TAG, "intent extras: " + data.getExtras().toString());
            }
        }

        Assert.assertNotNull("file uri in onActivityResult", mFileUri);
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "stored file name is " + mFileUri.toString());
        File file = getFileFromUri();
        if(file != null) {
            Bitmap bm = decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(file, 500, 500);
            imgMain.setImageBitmap(bm);
        }else{
            imgMain.setImageBitmap(null);
        }
    } else {
        parentActivity.finish();
    }

}

    private File getFileFromUri() {
    if(mFileUri != null) {
        try {
            URI uri;
            if(mFileUri.toString().startsWith("file://")){
                //normal path
                uri = URI.create(mFileUri.toString());
            } else {
                //support path
                uri = URI.create("file://" + mFileUri.toString());
            }
            File file = new File(uri);
            if (file != null) {
                //if (file.canRead()) {
                    return file;
                //}
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

I noticed that when I hit this line of code:

```
if (file.canRead()) {
                    return file;
                }
```

file.canRead() is TRUE when I take a picture, but FALSE when I CHOOSE a picture.  When I step through and look at the value of the "uri" variable, here they are:

```
file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/IMG_20150916_141518.jpg - this works
```

file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/IMG_20150916_141854.jpg - this doesn't work

any idea what's going on here?

UPDATE: tried using the InputStream approach from ContentResolver, but the bitmap still can't be displayed:

```
Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        InputStream imageStream = null;
        try {
             imageStream = parentActivity.getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage);
        }catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "cant load file " + mFileUri.toString());
        }

       Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
        imgMain.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

Comment: Since on most Android 4.4+ devices, neither of your actions will return a `file://` `Uri` in the first place, perhaps you might consider stopping thinking about files and focusing instead on using the `Uri` itself. Call `openInputStream()` on a `ContentResolver` to get an `InputStream`, which works for regular `file://` `Uri` *and* `content://` `Uri` values.

Comment: What is the value of `uri.getScheme()`? If it is file, perhaps changing `new File(uri);` to `new File(uri.getPath());` will work. Otherwise, you will need to use `ContentResolver` as CommonsWare suggested.

Comment: I tried the new constructor that jared offered File file = new File(uri.getPath()); with the same results, file.canread() is still false when choosing a file.  I'll look into commons' suggestion.  @CommonsWare do you have any resources/examples that would make it faster for me?

Comment: "do you have any resources/examples that would make it faster for me?" -- `getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData())`.

Comment: @CommonsWare still not working, will update above with my new code

Comment: "the bitmap still can't be displayed" -- what does that mean? If you are getting the `FileNotFoundException`, you might consider logging (third parameter to `Log.v()`) and posting the stack trace. If you are crashing elsewhere, post the stack trace.

Comment: that's the thing!  I'm not getting any exceptions "bm" is showing as a bitmap with properties and everything!  However, setting imgMain.setImageBitmap(bm) shows no image.